# Is there a way to make the firebase realtime database presence system detect disconnect faster

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I am creating a flutter app, it would be essential to detect almost immediately a user goes offline from the realtime/firestore database and notify other users of the same.

I have tried the recommended method of subscribing to .info/connected in the realtime DB and also update a firestore DB.

```dart
FirebaseDatabase.instance
        .reference()
        .child('.info')
        .child('connected')
        .onValue
        .listen((data) {
      if (data.snapshot.value == false) {
        // Internet has been disconnected
        setState(() {
          state.connected = false;
        });
        userFirestoreRef.updateData({
          'status': 'offline',
          'lastChanged': FieldValue.serverTimestamp(),
        });
      }
      userDbRef.onDisconnect().update({
        'status': 'offline',
        'lastChanged': ServerValue.timestamp
      }).then((_) async {
        // This resolves as soon as the server gets the request, not when the user disconnects
        setState(() {
          state.connected = true;
        });
        await userDbRef.update({
          'status': 'online',
          'lastChanged': ServerValue.timestamp,
        }).catchError((e) => debugPrint('Error in realtime db auth, $e'));

        await userFirestoreRef.updateData({
          'status': 'online',
          'lastChanged': FieldValue.serverTimestamp(),
        }).catchError((e) => debugPrint('Error in firestore auth, $e'));
      });
```

Once the internet is off, it takes about 1.5 minutes for the realtime db to detect the user disconnected, I would like this to maybe be 10 seconds maximum.

Comment: A disconnect in a network is always realized with a timeout. Network packages take time to traverse the network, be processed by the peer and a response sent back; sometimes more so, sometimes less. Since there’s no physical cable being actually “cut”, a “disconnect” can only be assumed if the peer does not respond within a certain timeframe. To allow a balance between a congested network and busy peer, 90 seconds is a typical timeout value.

Comment: Hi, how are you able to record the user presence on the app? Many people say to use stream builder but I don't think it's correct

Comment: Did you find solution for this issue ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are two ways a client can disconnected:

- a clean disconnect, where the client lets the server know that it's disappearing.
- a dirty disconnect, where the client disappears and it's up to the server to detect this condition.

For clean disconnects, the `onDisconnect` writes you defined will run immediately.

Dirty disconnects depend on socket time-outs, which means it may take multiple minutes before your `onDisconnect` writes happen. There is nothing you can do about this behavior, as it's an inherent part of how sockets work.

If you want a faster way to detect what clients are still connected, you can write a keep-alive in the database. Essentially: every 10 seconds write a sentinel value from every client.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time. How would this work exactly? Writing a sentinel value from every client

Comment: You'd just write `ServerValue.TIMESTAMP` periodically. https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/offline-capabilities#server-timestamps